# How do I turn on JMX in ActiveMQ 5.2

Tags: activemq-classic

Whats the proper way to enable JMX in ActiveMQ 5.2? I've seen conflicting documents, so I was wondering if anyone out there knows what the proper config file change should be. I think I might have it working by changing the batch file I use to start ActiveMQ, but I don't really know.

Answer (score 9):

```
<!-- Use the following to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in JMX -->
<managementContext>
  <managementContext createConnector="true" />
</managementContext>
```

Put this inside the bean of your broker in the activemq.xml file and it should do the trick. Your connector will be created in localhost:1099, and you shouldn't need to modify the batch file.
Regards,
Seb

Answer (score 3):

with a default installation, just edit your /bin/activemq file and setup the ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START property as follows...

> ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"

Answer (score 1):

What conflicting documents have you seen? [This one](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) explains it pretty well. There is no need to change any batch files.

Comment: If I add the attribute useJmx="true" then my ActiveMQ doesn't start up properly. I had to add the following line to my batch file. I got that from the installation of ActiveMQBrowser.

set SUNJMX=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false