# Unable to access JMX Console on ActiveMQ 5.12.0 VM

Tags: vagrant, activemq-classic, virtualbox, jmx, jconsole

I am attempting to get JMX Console working on a Vagrant VM box with ActiveMQ 5.12.0 manually installed. I've followed the guide on

- http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html

and numerous Stackoverflow troubleshooting questions:

- [Apache ActiveMQ browser can't connect to JMX console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093003/apache-activemq-browser-cant-connect-to-jmx-console)
- [How do I turn on JMX in ActiveMQ 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718948/how-do-i-turn-on-jmx-in-activemq-5-2)
- [configure JMX for ActiveMQ for remoting access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725202/configure-jmx-for-activemq-for-remoting-access)

but I am still not able to access the console from the host machine.

I've done the following steps:

- added useJmx="true" onto the <broker> tag in the activemq.xml file
- set the following management context in the activemq.xml file:

  ```
  <managementContext createConnector="true" rmiServerPort="1098" connectorPort="1099"/>
  ```
- set ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START environment variable to

  ```
  "\
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false\
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/usr/share/activemq/conf/jmx.password\
  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/usr/share/activemq/conf/jmx.access\
  "
  ```
- attempting to connect on

  ```
  service:jmx:rmi://192.168.150.117:1098/jndi/rmi://192.168.150.117:1099/jmxrmi
  ```
- using admin:activemq as username:password (specified in jmx.access and jmx.password)

This is the activemq.log file:

```
    2015-11-20 12:24:39,710 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@190c4838: startup date [Fri Nov 20 12:24:39 GMT 2015]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,094 | INFO  | PListStore:[/usr/share/activemq/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,191 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/usr/share/activemq/data/kahadb] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,232 | INFO  | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi://localhost:1098/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi | org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext | JMX connector
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,464 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.12.0 (localhost, ID:activemq.cdl.vm-56262-1448022282329-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,492 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://activemq.cdl.vm:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,498 | INFO  | Connector openwire started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,505 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: amqp://activemq.cdl.vm:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,510 | INFO  | Connector amqp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,525 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: stomp://activemq.cdl.vm:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,532 | INFO  | Connector stomp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,542 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: mqtt://activemq.cdl.vm:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,550 | INFO  | Connector mqtt started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,693 | INFO  | Listening for connections at ws://activemq.cdl.vm:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,698 | INFO  | Connector ws started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,706 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.12.0 (localhost, ID:activemq.cdl.vm-56262-1448022282329-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,720 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,730 | WARN  | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /usr/share/activemq/data/kahadb only has 10221 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available disk space: 10221 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:42,737 | WARN  | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb, whilst the temporary data directory: /usr/share/activemq/data/localhost/tmp_storage only has 10221 mb of usable space - resetting to maximum available 10221 mb. | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:43,444 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:43,444 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://0.0.0.0:8161/api/jolokia/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:43,538 | INFO  | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher' | /admin | main
    2015-11-20 12:24:43,950 | INFO  | jolokia-agent: No access restrictor found at classpath:/jolokia-access.xml, access to all MBeans is allowed | /api | main
```

When I try to connect it just says "Secure Connection Failed. Retry insecurely?". It then tries and fails again with "Connection Failed: Retry?"

Answer (score 0):

I set the following options on the ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START environment variable:

```
export ACTIVEMQ_SUNJMX_START="\
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote\
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false\
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false\
 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false\
"
```

And it now works.